# Swapping input "disabled" with "required"

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, I've been learning JS now for 6 months and have come across the first issue that I can't resolve and need some guidance, please.

I have a hidden input that is set to disabled like this....

```
<input name="input_35" id="input_3_35" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" disabled>
```

When a select option is selected the above input has "disabled" removed and show on the page, like this...

```
<input name="input_35" id="input_3_35" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to add a "required" when the "disabled" is removed like this...

```
<input name="input_35" id="input_3_35" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false required">
```

I have written the below code and for whatever reason simply doesn't work. Can anyone guide me what may be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
$('#input_3_35').attr('disabled') == "disabled" ?
    $("#input_3_35").prop('required',false); :
    $("#input_3_35").prop('required',true);
```

Comment: Actually it is not necessary to remove the „required“ attribute from an input element, when it is disabled. The browser (and also many javascript validation libraries) do not validate disabled elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the semicolon after `$("#input_3_35").attr('required',false)` and instead of `attr('disabled') == "disabled"` you should just check `attr('disabled') === true?`. Removing that semicolon should solve your problem.

You can use `attr` method to setAttribute as well.

```
$('#input_3_35').attr('disabled') == "disabled" ? $("#input_3_35").attr('required',false) : $("#input_3_35").attr('required',true);
```

Comment: While this is true, it's irrelevant to the problem and bad advice. `prop()` should be used over `attr()` where possible.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, I just figured out the actual problem in his code and suggesting another possible solution. Hope that is right.

Answer (score 0):

Your code expects `attr('disabled')` to return the string `disabled`. This will never happen as the `disable` attribute has no value.

A better approach is to use `prop()`, as this returns a boolean. Also note that the semi-colon after the first condition in your inline if statement will cause a syntax error - it needs to be removed.

```
$('#input_3_35').prop('disabled') ?
  $("#input_3_35").prop('required', false) :
  $("#input_3_35").prop('required', true);
```

Also note that the logic can be simplified to just this:

```
$("#input_3_35").prop('required', function() { return !this.disabled; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's much appreciated.

The code makes total sense but doesn't work. I can only guess it may be because the field is hidden and only shows when the select is used and that option is chosen.

Here's the code for that....

"<option value="An enthusiastic neighbour or friend" selected="selected">An enthusiastic neighbour or friend</option>"

Comment: It's possible. To debug the issue fully we'd really need to see a full working example which shows all relevant HTML and JS, and how and when the functions are called

Answer (score 0):

```js
// When a select option is selected
$("#something").on("change", evt => {
  // get the value of the option selected
  let value = evt.target.value;
  // try to get a reference to it in the DOM
  let el = $(value);
  // if the element exists
  if (el !== null) {
    // What I'm trying to achieve is to add a "required" when the "disabled" is removed like this...
    // remove the disabled property and add required
    el.prop({
      "disabled": false,
      "required": true
    });
  }
});
```

```css
[required] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #ff87a1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="something">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <!-- assign the id of the input as the value for the option that is controlling it -->
  <option value="#input_3_35">Enable</option>
</select>

<input name="input_35" id="input_3_35" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" disabled>
```